# CALayer animations and color blending

Tags: ios, core-animation, core-graphics

I am using CAShapeLayer to generate some shapes. Actually I have 4 CAShapeLayers that represent some triangles in the screen. I create the shapes using CGMutablePathRef and setting the path property of each CAShapeLayer. Triangles are in different shapelayers since I have to animate each triangle in a different way.

I perform some animations on my viewcontroller using CABasicAnimation and animating the path property of the CAShapeLayer, something like:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@”path”];
animation.duration = 2.0;
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
animation.repeatCount = 1e100f;
animation.autoreverses = YES;
animation.fromValue = (id)initialPath;
animation.toValue = (id)newPath;
[shapeLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@”animatePath”];
```

That's ok, I can draw shapes and animate them. My problem is that this blends the images using the default alpha blending (result = (alpha * foreground) + (1 - alpha) * background). What I want is to use multiply blending (kCGBlendModeMultiply), but I don't know how to mix CAShapeLayer drawing and blending modes. I've successfully drawn my shapes creating a custom UIView and overriding the drawRect method, but then I can't animate the shapes.

Has anyone had any success changing the color blending of a CAShapeLayer?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to change the blend of CALayer. You'd have to draw your paths in drawRect. Seems like this is something Apple should expose on iOS...